Connection refused error while accessing Kakfa set up in docker-container on VM from local system based using VM external IP
I have set up Kafka on my VM. It is working fine when I am using an external IP as 127.0.0.1 from the VM. (Able to produce and consume messages). But when I am trying to produce the messages locally, I see success messages producer but messages are not actually getting produced, so I tried to change the Advertiser lister from 127.0.0.1 to VM static IP and enabled all the related ports. Tried many solutions (listed below) but none of them seems to be working. Pasting complete docker-compose.file for your reference (with removed VM IP).
Can anyone help with this? Thanks in advance.
kafka3-1           | [2024-06-07 20:26:27,461] WARN [RequestSendThread controllerId=3] Controller 3's connection to broker kafka3:19094 (id: 3 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)

kafka3-1           | [2024-06-07 20:22:33,702] INFO Opening socket connection to server zoo1/192.168.224.4:2181. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
kafka3-1           | [2024-06-07 20:22:33,703] INFO SASL config status: Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
kafka3-1           | [2024-06-07 20:22:33,704] WARN Session 0x0 for sever zoo1/192.168.224.4:2181, Closing socket connection. Attempting to reconnect except it is a SessionExpiredException. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
kafka3-1           | java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
kafka3-1           |    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
kafka3-1           |    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:777)
kafka3-1           |    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:344)
kafka3-1           |    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1290)
zoo1-1             | [2024-06-07 20:22:33,744] INFO Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@51891008{/,null,AVAILABLE} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler)
kafka1-1           | [2024-06-07 20:22:33,779] INFO Opening socket connection to server zoo1/192.168.224.4:2181. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
kafka1-1           | [2024-06-07 20:22:33,779] INFO SASL config status: Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
kafka1-1           | [2024-06-07 20:22:33,781] WARN Session 0x0 for sever zoo1/192.168.224.4:2181, Closing socket connection. Attempting reconnect except it is a SessionExpiredException. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)


schema-registry-1  | [2024-06-07 20:22:28,716] INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -2 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
schema-registry-1  | [2024-06-07 20:22:28,716] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -2 (kafka2/192.168.224.2:19093) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Latest docker-compose.yml file.
    services:
  zoo1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.2
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zoo1:2888:3888
    networks:
      - kafka-network
      - airflow-kafka

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.2
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka1:19092,EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-<VM-IP>}:9092,DOCKER://host.docker.internal:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,DOCKER:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_CLASS_NAME: kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
      KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: "true"
    volumes:
      - kafka1_data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    networks:
      - kafka-network
      - airflow-kafka
    extra_hosts:
      - "kafka1:<VM-IP>"
  kafka2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.2
    ports:
      - "9093:9093"
      - "29093:29093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka2:19093,EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-<VM-IP>}:9093,DOCKER://host.docker.internal:29093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,DOCKER:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_CLASS_NAME: kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
      KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: "true"
    volumes:
      - kafka2_data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    networks:
      - kafka-network
      - airflow-kafka
    extra_hosts:
      - "kafka2:<VM-IP>"
  kafka3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.2
    ports:
      - "9094:9094"
      - "29094:29094"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka3:19094,EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-<VM-IP>}:9094,DOCKER://host.docker.internal:29094
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,DOCKER:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_CLASS_NAME: kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
      KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: "true"
    volumes:
      - kafka3_data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    networks:
      - kafka-network
      - airflow-kafka
    extra_hosts:
      - "kafka3:<VM-IP>"

  kafka-connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:7.3.2
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka1:19092,kafka2:19093,kafka3:19094
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: compose-connect-configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: compose-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: compose-connect-status
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 'kafka-connect'
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: 'INFO'
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: 'org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR'
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components'
    networks:
      - kafka-network
      - airflow-kafka

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.3.2
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka1:19092,kafka2:19093,kafka3:19094
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081
    volumes:
      - schema_registry_data:/var/lib/schema-registry/data
    networks:
      - kafka-network
      - airflow-kafka

  kafka-ui:
    container_name: kafka-ui
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    ports:
      - 8888:8080 # Changed to avoid port clash with akhq
    depends_on:
      - kafka1
      - kafka2
      - kafka3
      - schema-registry
      - kafka-connect
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: local
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:19092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://kafka1:19092
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_SCHEMAREGISTRY: http://schema-registry:8081
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_KAFKACONNECT_0_NAME: connect
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_KAFKACONNECT_0_ADDRESS: http://kafka-connect:8083
      DYNAMIC_CONFIG_ENABLED: 'true'
    networks:
      - kafka-network
      - airflow-kafka

volumes:
  kafka1_data:
  kafka2_data:
  kafka3_data:
  schema_registry_data:

networks:
  kafka-network:
  airflow-kafka:

Solutions I tried:

User VM IP and enabled all ports. e.g EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-<VM-IP>}:9094
Mofied /etc/hosts file for DNS resolving of docker kafka brokers host e.g added VM_IP kafka1 for each kafka broker including zoo
Added below in docker-compose file for DNS host mapping of kafka host to VM IP

extra_hosts:
  - "kafka3:<VM-IP>"

Also, when I accessing kafka ui its giving error
500 Internal Server Error: Failed to resolve 'schema-registry' [A(1)] after 2 queries
Attaching screenshot for the reference (Error is at bottom right corner):

Please help me with directions incase I have missed anything. Thanks a lot.

My Bad. I thought I had already added rules to allow incoming traffic on VM but I din't not which was causing the connection issue.
After exposing the ports on the VM, we need to ensure that the firewall allows traffic on those ports.
Below is the command I had to run after exposing these port in VM settings.
# Allow Zookeeper port
sudo ufw allow 2181/tcp

# Allow Kafka ports
sudo ufw allow 9092/tcp
sudo ufw allow 9093/tcp
sudo ufw allow 9094/tcp

